# Which Lego board games come with minifigures instead of microfigures?

Tags: minifigures, sets, lego-games

Of all the LEGO board games that have been produced so far, which ones come with minifigures instead of microfigures?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Various minifigures are in included in:

**LEGO Chess Sets:**

- [Castle](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?G=852001) - 24 minifigures
- [Giant Fantasy Era](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?G=852293) - 33 minifigures
- [Knight's Kingdom](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?G=G678) - 24 minifigures
- [Pirates](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?G=852751) - 24 minifigures
- [Vikings](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?G=G577) - 24 minifigures

**LEGO Tic-Tac-Toe Sets:**

- [Castle](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?G=852132) - 10 minifigures
- [Police](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?G=G574) - 10 minifigures
- [Pirates](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?G=852750) - 10 minifigures

**Other LEGO Games:**

- [Ludo](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?G=G572) (a variant of parcheesi) - 16 minifigures
- [Creationary](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?G=3844) - 1 minifigure
- [Time Cruisers Game](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?G=GA04) - 5
  minifigures
- [Creator Board Game Deluxe](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?G=G08553) - 4 minifigures
- [Constructionary](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?G=GA08539) (a variant of charades) - 2 minifigures
- [Knight's Kingdom the Game](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?G=218158) (never released in English) - 5 minifigures